# Is it possible to make a function in Java to detect if any of the params passed to it is null? (varargs)

Tags: java

I want a function to detect if any of the params passed to it is null.
If having null, then return true. Otherwise false.
And I want it be varargs.
But there be a special request that if I passed an Object array to it which is not null, but some contents of some indexes of the array is null, then we shall make this function return false, as the array itself is not null.

I tried to solve it with some overload but...just not that easy.

```
public static boolean isAnyNullInParams(final Object firstObject, final Object... array) {
        if (firstObject == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (array == null) {
            return true;
        }
        for (Object object : array) {
            if (object == null) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isAnyNullInParams(final Object[] array) {
        return array == null;
    }

    public static boolean isAnyNullInParams() {
        return false;
    }
```

At least the result code must be able to pass:

```
    @Test
    public void isAnyNullTest() {
        Assertions.assertFalse(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams());
        Assertions.assertTrue(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(null));
        Assertions.assertTrue(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(1, null));
        Assertions.assertTrue(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(2, 2, 2, null));
        Assertions.assertTrue(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(null, 4, 3, 3, 5));
        Assertions.assertTrue(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(4, null, 3, 5));
        Assertions.assertFalse(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(4, true, 3, 5));
        Assertions.assertFalse(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(new Object[]{null, null, null}));
        Assertions.assertFalse(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(1, new Object[]{null}));
        Assertions.assertFalse(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(1, (Object) new Object[]{null}));
    }
```

---

### added 2019/06/04

I don't know if it be right to do so but I finally choose to abandon varargs and try to use generate.

https://github.com/XenoAmess/commonx/blob/830584220a27fb3bbc1d7204cd7888e07c305b6b/src/main/java-templates/com/xenoamess/commonx/java/lang/IllegalArgumentExceptionUtilsx.java

Yes it can work now though ugly, maybe far too ugly. 
Still, I wonder if there be an equal and easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Mark Assertions.assertFalse(ArrayUtilsx.isAnyNullInParams(1, new Object[]{null}));

Comment: @Mark Java think the new Object[]{null} is that array in public static boolean isAnyNullInParams(final Object firstObject, final Object... array) , thus return true.

Comment: when you pass an array as an argument it uses this overload: `isAnyNullInParams(final Object[] array)` which means that it only does this check: `return array == null;` so this overload needs to check all elements of the array too.

Comment: @Chris Rollins That function is exactly the what I want... I just want to check if the array is null itself， and shall not looking into its elements.

Comment: sorry for my poor English but you can see the test code  to see what I want.

Comment: what happens if you make an overload with this signature: `isAnyNullInParams(final Object firstObject, final Object[] array)` ?

Comment: Error:(1610, 27) java: cannot declare both isAnyNullInParams(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object[]) and isAnyNullInParams(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object...) in com.xenoamess.commonx.org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtilsx

Comment: It seems like the problem comes from `null` literals passed as arguments. The compiler cannot tell if it should be `Object` or `Object[]` when passed to varargs. But are there actually cases when you will pass `null` literals?

Comment: @Chris Rollins this function is used to determin if any of the params is null so yes.

Comment: @XenoAmess Does a solution exist? This seems either incomplete as an assignment, either impossible if you ask me.

Comment: @Yassin Hajaj No idea...I'm considering about not using varargs and just put 255 functions there.

Comment: You cannot do this. `Object...` translates to `Object[]`, and you're requiring `m(null)` to return `true` and `m(new Object[] { null, null, null })` to return `false`. And once you overload your method, the compiler cannot pick a method any longer due to the ambiguity of passing `null`.

Comment: @XenoAmess I believe my answer should solve your problem, please try it out and let me know if ti fulfills all your requirements.

Comment: why would you pass a null literal? you already know its null.

Comment: oh also if you really need to pass a literal, you can just cast it to `Object`

Comment: @XenoAmess And *why* exactly do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if overloading method like what you're doing is the best approach. It might be the simplest but it seems a bit cluttered where you have to account for many different situations. What comes to mind is to use [Bean Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) where you would validate any and all of your method parameters according to your conditions. However that would probably require you to do some kind of method interception using AOP proxies which perhaps adds more complexity then what you are willing to go for.

In any case, to solve your particular problem I've added another check for your special condition and now all your tests pass:

```
public static boolean isAnyNullInParams(final Object firstObject, final Object... array)
{
    if (firstObject == null) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (array == null) {
        return true;
    }
    /*
     * Special case where an array contains a single null element
     */
    if (array.length == 1 && array[0] == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (Object object : array) {
        if (object == null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:** It would seem my solution doesn't solve your problem as @VoroX kindly pointed out. I believe you need to rethink this whole approach and perhaps use Bean validation as I've mentioned in the intro. Let me know if you are more interested in this, I would be happy to show you.

Comment: Won't work if a single array has multiple elements of which one is null, so it passes the tests but it won't solve the question (`isAnyNullInParams("Test", new String[]{null, "Test"})` returns true).

Comment: @VoroX You're right, the whole problem is confusing me to no end, I don't think his whole approach is the right way to go to begin with.

Comment: Well my own attempt isn't much better... And I agree with you on the wrong approach

Comment: @VoroX Time to upvote each other and feel better about ourselves in spite of our blatant failures.

Comment: Totally agree ,)

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible, at least if the array you provide is a `Object[]` and here's why:

The `Object...` parameter assumes that, if you supply a single `Object[]`, this array is the actual parameter, so it's values will be set as the values of your vararg. If you just supply an `Object[]` then:

`Object... params` is equal to this: `Object[] params`.

However there is a way to do this if you supply an array which is not an `Object[]`, for example a `String[]`. While testing I found out that if you use `params.getClass().getCanonicalName()` you will get:

`java.lang.Object[]` if you use mulitple parameters (like `containsNull(null, "Test")`), but

`java.lang.String[]` if you supply a `String[]` (like `containsNull(new String[]{null, "Test"})`).

Here's a method using this:

```
public static boolean containsNull(Object... params) {
    if (params == null)
        return true;

    if (params.getClass().getCanonicalName().endsWith("Object[]")) {
        for (Object o : params)
            if (o == null)
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here're some results:

```
containsNull("Test1", "Test2", 34);                  //Returns false
containsNull(null);                                  //Returns true
containsNull(null, "Test");                          //Returns true
containsNull(new String[]{null, "Test"});            //Returns false -> Does work with arrays
containsNull(new Object[]{"Test", null});            //Returns true! -> Does not work with Object[]
containsNull(new Object[]{"Test1", null}, "Test2");  //Returns false -> Does work with more params
```

*(Keep in mind I haven't considered any external libraries outside of the standard jdk)*